# Probability of meeting someone infected

Tags: probability

Let's take Italy as an example. There are $60,360,000$ citizens out of which are currently $95,262$ infected. What is the probability that when you randomly pick $100,000$ citizens of Italy, there will be **at least one** infected?

I started like this: $\frac{60,360,000}{95,262} = 633.6$. This means that every $633.6$-th citizen of Italy is infected. So when considering all citizens, there is a chance of $\frac{95,262}{60,360,000} \cdot 100 = 1.58 \%$ meeting someone infected. So what about the chances out of $100,000$?

My guess was that $100,000$ is $603.6$ times smaller, so the probability would be also $603.6$ time smaller, meaning $\frac{1.58}{603.6}=0.0026 \%$. Is that a correct assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's a repeated experiment, (I'll assume, independent) the chance that none are infected is $(1- \frac{I}{N})^n$, where $I$ is the number of infected, $N$ the total population, and $n$ the sample size. This binomial chance is a good approximation for the hypergeometric one here, due to the large numbers involved. So at least one is $1 - (1- \frac{I}{N})^n$, which is pretty close to $1$ I think.

Comment: So the probability is $$(1 - \frac{95,262}{60,360,000})^{100,000}) = 0.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997$$which is actually unsurprising. Thank you.

Comment: @tomashauser like I said, pretty close to $1$..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the converse probability. $P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)$.

Since the sample is not very large we can assume approximately the probability $p=\frac{95,262}{60,360,000}=0.00157823\approx 0.157823\%$. Here you missed a $0$.

Then $P(X\geq 1)=1-(1-0.00158)^{100000}=1-\left(1- \frac{157.82}{100000}\right)^{100000}$

This is approximately $\boxed{1-e^{-157.82}}=1-0=1$

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively straightforward binomial distribution. First, find the probability of encountering an infected individual:
\begin{equation}
\frac{95262}{60360000} \approx .1578\%
\end{equation}

Then, you can take the binomial probability mass function
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
n \\
k
\end{pmatrix}
 p^kq^{n-k}
\end{equation}
where $n$ is the total population you encounter, $k$ is the number of infected individuals you encounter, $p$ is the probability of encountering an infected individual, and $q$ is the probability of encountering an uninfected individual.

If you want to find the probability of encountering exactly one infected individual, do:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
100 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
(.001578)^1(1-.001578)^{99}
\end{equation}
But note that this is not the result you asked for. You wanted the chance of encountering **at least one** infected individual. So, to find that result using this method, you would need to add the probability of encountering exactly one infected individual, and the probability of encountering exactly two infected individuals, and the probability of infecting at least three, etc. until you have the chance that you encounter one, or two, or three, etc. infected individuals (which is the same as the probability of encountering at least one infected person).

However, this route is obviously a complete pain. So instead, I recommend thinking about the chance that you encounter exactly zero infected individuals. What would this result look like and how would it be relevant to your question?

Hope this helps!